# Loop Through Defined Subfolders Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can I modify the code so that the folder (where the file is located) plus the subfolders are queried? At the moment only the folder in which the file is located is read out. I would like to activate this function (eg AllSubfolders) with True or False. And in addition, a way to query certain subfolders by specifying different paths (for this I would set the AllSubfolders function to false).

Unfortunately, after several attempts, I do not come to this success. My VBA knowledge is not good.

I've tried to implement following code with mine:

```
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String

HostFolder = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Dokumente\"

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ' Operate on each file
    Next
End Sub
```

but without success. With the following Code i copy data from multiple files in the Folder of the Active Workbook. I want to set True or False for searching subfolders and give specific paths to copy data from.

```
Sub Copy_Data_from_Files_in_Folder()

ActiveSheet.Range("A4:I1000").ClearContents 'Vorgegebenen Tabelleninhalt vor dem Kopieren der Daten löschen

Dim StatusCalc

'Makrobremsen lösen - Am Beginn eines Makros
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    StatusCalc = .Application.Calculation 'Aktuellen Berechnungsmodus merken
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Const sXlsPath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Dokumente\" 'Pfad zu bestimmtem Ordner

'oder wenn sich die Dateien im selben Ordner befinden

sXlsPath = ThisWorkbook.Path 'Datei im gleichen Ordner wie Auswertungsdateien

Const iStartZeile = 4 'Angeben, ab welcher Zeile eingefügt werden soll
Const iStartSpalte = 1 'Angeben, ab welcher Spalte eingefügt werden soll
Const Zellen = "D3,K3,K7,H34,R3,D5,K5,R5,A29" 'Angeben, welche Zellen kopiert werden sollen

Dim oFso As Object, oFile As Object, oWkb1 As Workbook, oWks0 As Worksheet, oWks1 As Worksheet
Dim aCells As Variant, iNextLine As Long, i As Integer

Set oWks0 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

aCells = Split(Zellen, ","):  iNextLine = iStartZeile

Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

For Each oFile In oFso.GetFolder(sXlsPath).Files
    If LCase(oFso.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "xlsx" Then 'Hier den Dateityp anpassen
        If ThisWorkbook.Path <> oFile.Name Then
            Set oWkb1 = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
            Set oWks1 = oWkb1.Sheets(1)
            For i = 0 To UBound(aCells)
                oWks0.Cells(iNextLine, iStartSpalte).Offset(0, i) = oWks1.Range(Trim(aCells(i))).Value
            Next
            oWkb1.Close False
            iNextLine = iNextLine + 1
        End If
    End If
Next

Beenden: 'Sprungadresse zum Beenden diese Makros
'Makrobremsen zurücksetzen - vor dem Beenden eines Makros
  With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = StatusCalc
    .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you set "Subfolder" to in the first code?

Comment: I set nothing, only tried to combine first code (which i‘ve found in this forum) with mine

Comment: I tend to use a DOS command prompt when searching recursive for files.  E.g. try `dir *.txt /s` to see all text files found not just in current directory but all subdirectories.  To run this from VBA one uses VBA.Shell.  [An added bonus to this is that the shelled process will multi-task with your code]

Comment: @SMeaden Another advantage is speed of processing.  And then the OP can filter the list for the subfolders of interest.